# ajax response popup using fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

first I have send the http ajax request to the server and return the response. Then I need to popup response using fancy box. I have tried several ways in many times. Unfortunately I couldn't find a clear method,

here is my code,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnInvoiceNo').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Return_Invoice", "QuickReports")",
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "",
                 success: function (data) {
                     alert(data);
                     $.fancybox({
                         'content': data
                     });
                     $('#popup_box').html(data);
                     $("#popup_box").fancybox();

                 },
                 error: function (e) {
                     alert("Error");
                 }
             });
         });
         });
</script>
```

Comment: any console errors??

Comment: no, Ihave debug program, the respose already exist

Comment: have you tried `$.fancybox(data)`? did you get the alert `alert(data);`?

Comment: @JFK yeah I got alert with data

Comment: so `$.fancybox(data)` should do the trick (I guess you should remove `$('#popup_box').html(data)` and `$('#popup_box').fancybox()` from the `success` setting)